# Is $f(x)=\left.\begin{cases}x\,\text{sgn}(\sin\frac{1}{x})&\text{if $x\neq0$}\\0&\text{if $x=0$}\end{cases}\right\}$ Riemann integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, riemann-integration

> For $x\in[-1,1]$, let
> $$
> f(x)=
> \begin{cases}
> x\,\operatorname{sgn}(\sin\frac{1}{x}),  &\text{if $x\neq0$} \\
> 0,  &\text{if $x=0$} 
> \end{cases}
> $$
> where $\text{sgn}$ denotes the signum function. Then:
>
> 1. $f$ is continuous on $[-1,1]$
> 2. $f$ is not differentiable at any point of $[-1,1]$
> 3. $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[-1,1]$.
> 4. The set of points of discontinuity of $f$ in $[-1,1]$ is finite.

I found this question in a previous year entrance paper. The answer given is option $3$.
Now, I know that $f$ is discontinuous at $x=0$, and that $f$ is differentiable
at many points in $[-1,1]$. But what about options $3$ and $4$? Aren't they both essentially the same?

Comment: I always cringe when I see ”Reimann” integrable on this site. It is "Riemann”!!!

Comment: I wonder why this happens so often: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Reimann

Comment: @MartinR According to ["How common is your last name"](https://projects.newsday.com/databases/long-island/census-last-names/?where=name^reimann&offset=0) the last name "Reimann" is more common than "Riemann". But I digress

Comment: The set of points of discontinuites is a countably infiinite set so 3) is true and 4) is false.

Comment: Wonder why is $f$ discontinuous at $x=0$.

Comment: @MartinR yeah my bad i didnt check the title before posting.

Comment: @RijoPaul $f$ **is** continuous at $0$ as $\vert f(x) \vert \le \vert x \vert$ for all $x \in [-1,1]$.

Comment: @EricMonlye ,@mathcounterexamples.net  Thanks i now understand what my mistake was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $0 < \epsilon <1$, $f$ is piecewise differentiable on $[-1,-\epsilon] \cup [\epsilon , 1]$ and therefore Riemann integrable on those intervals. Also $f$ is discontinuous at all points of the infinite set $S=\{1/k\pi \mid k \in \mathbb Z\}$.

This makes 1., 2. and 4. claims false.

Finally $f$ is bounded on $[-1,1]$. So given the above, $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[-1,1]$ and 3. is correct.

*Recall that a map $f$ that is bounded on $[a,b]$ and Riemann integrable on all $[c,b]$ with $a<c<b$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$.*

Comment: A bounded function is not necessarily Riemann integrable.

Comment: @MartinR Right. But a function that is bounded on $[a, b]$ and Riemann integrable on all $[\epsilon, b]$ for $a< \epsilon <b$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$.